# Looping back to a previous line within a function

Tags: r

In the below function, I would like to control the input so that if any value but the first three choices (any value that does not equal 1-3) are entered the function will loop back to the original question.

```
T<-function(){
Load<-readline("
Choose Task 
1 Task 1
2 Task 2
3 Task 3 ")
for(i in 1:10){
    if(Load=="")
    {print.noquote("No Value Entered"); Load<-readline("
Choose Task 
1 Task 1
2 Task 2
3 Task 3 ")
    }else
    if(Load==1)
    {source("/Users/JD/Desktop/R1.R")}
    else
    if(Load==2)
    {source("/Users/JD/Desktop/R2.R",print.eval=TRUE)}
    else
    if(Load==3)
    {source("/Users/JD/Desktop/R3.R",print.eval=TRUE)}
    else
    {print.noquote("Must enter 1-3"); ** loop back to "Choose Task"**}



}}
```

So where I have the ** would be a line looping back to the second line of the code. I've already controlled for a "blank" response, but I would like to do something similar for anything not equaling 1-3. If looping back is not allowed, perhaps there may be a different way to get the same effect.

Comment: Good idea ttmaccer, that works just fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `switch` and recursion

```
ChooseTask <- function() {
    Load <- readline("Choose Task. 1, 2, or 3: ")
    switch(Load, 
           "1"={cat("1", "\n")},
           "2"={cat("2", "\n")},
           "3"={cat("3", "\n")},
            {
                print.noquote("Must enter 1-3") 
                ChooseTask()
            })
}
> ChooseTask()
Choose Task. 1, 2, or 3: 2
2 
> ChooseTask()
Choose Task. 1, 2, or 3: 5
[1] Must enter 1-3
Choose Task. 1, 2, or 3: 1
1
```

Comment: Just replace `cat("1", "\n")`, etc. with what you want --  `source("/Users/JD/Desktop/R1.R")` for example

Answer (score 3):

I would actually advise against the answers provided so far and suggest you use the handy `menu` function which basically does what you want for you.

```
> menu(c("Task1", "Task2", "Task3"), title = "Choose Task")
Choose Task 

1: Task1
2: Task2
3: Task3

Selection: 4
Enter an item from the menu, or 0 to exit
Selection: 1
[1] 1
```

The result of menu will either be 0, 1, 2, or 3.

Edit: To please GSee ... this is how you could refine it to actually do what the user wants

```
T <- function(){
    choice <- menu(c("Task1", "Task2", "Task3"), title = "Choose Task, or 0 to exit")

    switch(choice,
           source("/Users/JD/Desktop/R1.R"),                    # 1
           source("/Users/JD/Dekstop/R2.R, print.eval = TRUE"), # 2
           source("/Users/JD/Desktop/R3.R, print.eval = TRUE")) # 3
}
```

If the user chooses 0 then the switch statement won't execute any of the inputs.

Comment: Yeah. Ok, but then what?  You still need a `switch` or `if`

Comment: Sure but you still get an answer in the desired range.  You could then write some code that uses `switch` or `if` to do what you want without having to worry that you have an out of range value which is what I perceived as the main issue.

Comment: @GSee - I added an example of actually doing what the user wants.  I personally think this is much cleaner than having a recursive switch statement.

Comment: +1 `menu` also does some extra error checking that my function doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a simple loop:

```
choice <- 0
while( !( choice %in% 1:3 ) ) {
   choice <- readline('Choose 1, 2, or 3:')
}
```

Comment: you still need a `switch` or `if` to deal with `choice`

Comment: @GSee, yes, but that can come after the loop and can be the same (or similar to) as the code in the original question.

Comment: Fair enough. +1 for an alternate approach.